# Reactive R/Shiny app "forgets" variable state after other reactive variable changes

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive

Below is a reproducible example. When you click in the histogram area, a textbox appears showing the location of that click. But when you move the slider in the sidepanel, the textbox disappears and you have to click the histogram again to make it re-appear. How can I ensure that once the plot is clicked, the textbox remains (and keeps the same content) until the next click occurs, even if the slider is moved?

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
            label = "Number of bins:",
            min = 1,
            max = 50,
            value = 30)

    ),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot",click = "plot_click"),
      verbatimTextOutput("click_x")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$click_x <- renderText({
    input$plot_click$x
  })


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    x    <- faithful$waiting
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "#75AADB", border = "white",
       xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)",
       main = "Histogram of waiting times")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional output will do the trick:

```
output$click_x <- renderText({
    if(is.null(input$plot_click$x)) "Select point in graph" else input$plot_click$x
})
```

if you want to store the previous value, you can apply the condition to a variable attribution. You could do it with observeEvent:

```
observeEvent(input$plot_click$x, {
    var <- input$plot_click$x

    output$click_x <- renderText({
      var
    })
  })
```